# Create a select query to get employee name, total salary of employee, hobby name(comma-separated - you need to use subquery for hobby name)

Tags: mysql, query, subquery

see the below query table.

**Create an “employee” database and 4 tables (hobby, employee, employee_salary, employee_hobby).
hobby: id, name
employee: id, first_name, last_name, age, mobile_number, address
employee_salary: id, foreign key of employee, salary
employee_hobby: id, foreign key of the employee, foreign key of hobby**

I execute the following query

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) AS full_name
     , SUM(es.salary) AS total_salary
     , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(h.name) 
        FROM hobby h 
        INNER JOIN hobby 
            ON h.id = eh.fk_hobby_id
       ) AS hobby_name 
FROM employee_hobby eh
INNER JOIN employee e 
    ON e.id = eh.fk_employee_id
INNER JOIN employee_salary es 
    ON es.fk_employee_id = eh.fk_employee_id
GROUP BY eh.fk_employee_id;
```

but the in this query hobby_name raw gets multiple hobby_name names that are not defined in the hobby table.
and I have to complete this task by using the subquery
Here is my OUTPUT Image.[image]

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Please take your time to read [ask] and then consider reading up on [Markdown Editor Help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Instead of posting screen shots consider using [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) and reading the helpful post [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/15356) from out Meta Site. Please also consider cleaning up the tags you are using. Your screenshot seems to be referencing a **MySQL** database, so you should remove the **`sql-server`** and **`sql-server-2012`** tags.  Thanks and good luck.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(h.name)` -- Please elaborate on why there are multiple rows (names) for a single hobby.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of ddl and sample data makes it difficult to guess where the problem might be, but the following looks very suspicious:

```
INNER JOIN hobby 
    ON h.id = eh.fk_hobby_id
```

It means that you will multiply the number of hobbies for each employee with the cardinality of the hobby table. You may want to try:

```
SELECT CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) AS full_name
     , SUM(es.salary) AS total_salary
     , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(h.name) 
        FROM hobby h 
        WHERE h.id = eh.fk_hobby_id
       ) AS hobby_name 
FROM employee_hobby eh
INNER JOIN employee e 
    ON e.id = eh.fk_employee_id
INNER JOIN employee_salary es 
    ON es.fk_employee_id = eh.fk_employee_id
GROUP BY eh.fk_employee_id;
```

Group by eh.fk_employee_id may or may not be correct, but it is hard to tell without ddl for the tables.